# Acessar SelectedItem do Combobox Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Coloquei os itens dentro do combobox da seguinte forma:

```
cmbSituacao.DisplayMember = "Text";
cmbSituacao.ValueMember = "Value";
cmbSituacao.Items.Add(new {Text = "TODOS", Value = "000000"});

foreach(var sit in recSituacao)
{
  cmbSituacao.Items.Add(new {Text = sit.DESCRICAO, Value = sit.ID_SITUACAO });
  cmbSituacao.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Mas não consigo acessar os valores, segue o código:

```
object ss = cmbSituacao.SelectedItem;
if (cmbSituacao.GetItemText(cmbSituacao.SelectedItem).Equals("TODOS"))
  filtro = filtro.And(s => s.ID_SITUACAO == cmbSituacao.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: Não consegue, por quê?

Comment: porque quando eu acesso o SelectedItem ele não disponibiliza o "Text" nem o "Value", ali na imagem ele está retornando o Text pois estou usando o GetItemText, mas preciso mesmo é acessar o "Value" e este não consigo por nada, alguma ideia?

Comment: como o nome diz, é um `SelectedItem`, ou seja, o mesmo objeto que você criou, e a partir dele você consegue acessar o Text e Value

Comment: Troque a imagem pelo seu código

Comment: Obrigado, o conceito eu sei, quero entender como acessar, vc saberia, utilizando meu código acima? Ricardo Pontual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na realidade o seu código necessita de várias melhorias. Primeiramente você deve utilizar a propriedade `DataSource` do componente `ComboBox` para preencher os itens de forma que você possibilite a utilização correta dos recursos do componente. Para isso crie uma classe `ViewModel` para o `ComboBox`:

```
public class ComboViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Esta classe será o seu modelo portanto crie uma lista temporária que receberá os seus itens e depois sete esta lista como a propriedade `DataSource` do componente.

```
List<ComboViewModel> listaTemporaria = new List<ComboViewModel>()
{
    new ComboViewModel { Text = "TODOS", Value = "000000" }
};

listaTemporaria.AddRange(recSituacao.Select(sit => new ComboViewModel{  Text = sit.DESCRICAO, Value = sit.ID_SITUACAO }).ToList());

cmbSituacao.DataSource = listaTemporaria;
cmbSituacao.DisplayMember = "Text";
cmbSituacao.ValueMember = "Value";
cmbSituacao.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Diante disto quando for acessar o valor selecionado no ComboBox utilize o código abaixo:

```
ComboViewModel itemSelecionado = cmbSituacao.SelectedItem as ComboViewModel;

if (itemSelecionado != null && itemSelecionado.Text != "TODOS")
  filtro = filtro.And(s => s.ID_SITUACAO == itemSelecionado.Value);
```

Qualquer dúvida me avise, estou sem o Visual Studio agora e fiz no bloco de notas, pode haver algum erro.

Comment: Julio Borges, era exatamente isso, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @user2929918 OK, aceite a resposta por favor, para ajudar outras pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida.